# Orchard CMS + url open in canonical form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, canonical-form, orchardcms-1.8

I am using Orchard CMS, I want to do the url open with canonical form like.

If i press url without 'www' extension it will need to redirect url with www.domain.com.

I mean redirect with www extension.

Is this one is right module for www redirection : `http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Contrib.RewriteRules`

or  is there any one module from below url?

```
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Search?searchTerm=tag%3A%20Redirect
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRules should definitely help you to achieve that. Personally, i prefer to use IIS where  is possible.

Answer (score 0):

'www' redirection is usually done at the DNS level.

You need a DNS record for the domain and one for www.domain.

[Microsoft article on www DNS records](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168322)

Comment: you can't do a redir via dns, has to be done at the destination server.